# Theorem on Cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

In Bartle's book there is a theorem saying that if $c$ is a cluster point of a set $A \subset  \mathbb{R}$ if and only if every neighbourhood of $c$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. If every neighbourhood of $c$ contains infinitely many points of $A$ then it will surely become a cluster point of $A$.

I tried the proof in this way If $\delta$ is any positive number a $\delta-$ neighbourhood of $c$ will contain at least one $a_{1} \neq c$,such that $a_{1} \in A$. Choose new $\delta$ as $|c-a_{1}|$. This time I will get another $a_{2} \in A, a_{2} \neq c$. Proceeding similarly I will get a infinite number of $a_{n}$'s which is in $A$.

Advantage of this proof is  the same $a_{n}$'s work as a convergent sequence in $A$ which converges to $c$, and each $a_{n} \neq c$.This is the sequential criteria for cluster point.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The proof is correct. In particular $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots \}$ are all inside your $\delta$ neighborhood.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Your method is pretty much the way that it's usually done.

Comment: It seems that main purpose of your question is to ask about correctness of this particular proof. If that's the case, the tag ([tag:proof-verification]) should probably be used..

Comment: Can we use the same argument for both the proofs...Or should we use $\delta= \frac{1}{n}$ and reduce the length of the interval